# How to Activite form when clicked anywhere on the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, activation

MY C# app workd fine and stays on top whenever asked to. What I face and want is :

Suppose my app is open and another app (say Notepad) is also opened halfly overlapping my app window. When we click anywhere on Notepad, it gets activated. Whereas with my app, I got to click the top bar of the window to make it active. Why so ? I want to make my app active and bring to front when user clicks anywhere on the form and not just hte top bar.

What do I need to set or implement to accomplish this ?

Comment: I haven't this problem. Create new simple project and compare with yours app. Or give us some more details

Comment: I created another project where there is nothing inthe form and tried the same situation. And on clicking anywhere in that form it comes to front.  What details do you need tell, will share - I just don't understand what to put here as the app is a huge one. But will post all details that you need - just give me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with overridding WndProc. One unnecessary statement was removed and things got solved out.Thanks to all of you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do that ,on Form1_MousClick Event put this Code

```
bool top = this.TopMost;
this.TopMost = true;
this.TopMost = top;
```

Comment: TopMost is set as default only i.e. False. I added MouseClick event and added above code "this.TopMost = True;" Didn't work. Tried with "this.BringToFront()". Added a MessageBox also, but that is never shown only - So MouseClick is not being fired or Caught !! Hmmm.

Comment: Try to hide the form and show it again ,or Minimize and Maximize it.

Comment: Because you have a better solution ?!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, if you click anywhere on a Window, it gets focus and becomes the topmost window, unless another window is 'Always on top'.

Comment: Windows Explorer & my app is open and visible but Win Explorer overlaps half screen of my app. Win Exp has focus. I click on my app form (in middle), focus from win exp is lost. On clicking TAB components are not focused in my app (so it doesn't have focus I believe). When I click on the title bar of my app, it comes on top and has full focus. NOW, When I click to my app (in form middle where no components are placed) the focus from win exp is lost, but mine is not fully activated also. How do I make it activated and bring it on front like by pressing on titlebar it happens.

Comment: Hmm, the above is the scenario by clicking on place where there is no componetns. But if I click on my app compoents like picture, Label, Box, etc then it acts correctly like pressing Title bar. But when clicking at place where there are no components, it reacts differently. How to handle those locations also where their are no componets and user clicks there and the app comes on top ?

Comment: Either you've written some code to explicitly stop it coming to the front of the screen, or you're using a component or library that does that, or there's a bug in said component or library.  Windows does not behave the way you describe.

Comment: agreed there must be some bug or maybe setting somewhere that makes ut ac like this. But have not explicitly stopped it from coming. Why would it not come to front when clicked on a place where their are no components and if clicked on a component, it comes up. I use standard components only. I don't think this is any component or library issue. What possible settings  could affect such a result ? As if clicked on a location where component (eg. GroupBox, PictureBox, etc) is placed it comes on top; but where nnothing is placed it doesn't come on top, Do you have idea of any Settings ?